# Bind two html view with one js template on meteor.js

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have 2 separate html templates for desktop and mobile size with common logic. Is there possibility bind these html templates with one js template ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to do that is to use a [dynamic template](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic) to pick the mobile or desktop template and attach the js to the parent template - the one that embeds the dynamic template.

Comment: Thanks, It can be solution. but is it really the easiest way? is there no legal api for binding logic with view?

Comment: Using blaze to switch layouts is easier `{{if isMobile}}{{> mobileTemplate}}{{else}}{{> desktopTemplate}}` but then each template needs its own helpers. Dynamic templates are the only workaround I know to reuse js across templates (besides global helpers).

Answer (score 1):

In my case solution was next
I used Blaze to switch between templates like adviced me Michel Floyd, and helpers  were just passed to datacontext to both templates.
My general html page view and  part of js template  below

```
<template name="signUpTutor">
{{#if equals view 'mobile'}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template="signUpTutorMobile" data=dataContext}}
{{else}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template="signUpTutorDesktop" data=dataContext}}
{{/if}}
```

```
Template.signUpTutor.helpers({
'equals': function (a, b) {
    return a == b;
},
'dataContext': function () {
    var dataContext = {}
    dataContext.subjects = Subjects.find();
    dataContext.ageOptions = function () {
        var ageOptions = [];
        for (var i = 0, a = 19; a <= 99; i++, a++) {
            ageOptions[i] = a;
        }
        return ageOptions;
    };
    dataContext.experienceOptions = function () {
        var experienceOptions = [];
        for (var i = 0, a = 1; a <= 60; i++, a++) {
            experienceOptions[i] = a;
        }
        return experienceOptions;
    };
    return dataContext;
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to do this. It allows you to specify breakpoints (ie screen sizes) at which the HTML rendered will change. This will allow the desktop user to see the mobile view simply by resizing the window.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Its clear, but I cannot use only media query. First of all I already have two separate html layout and secon of all one view is modal window and another one normal page